# TextBoxのPreviewMouseDownイベント内でShowDialog()をすると、TextBoxをクリックしてもカーソルが合わない

Tags: c#, wpf

WPFにて、TextBoxのPreviewMouseDownイベント内でShowDialog()をすると、TextBoxをクリックしてもカーソルが合わなくなってしまいます。
PreviewMouseDownイベント内でShowDialog()をした後はPreviewMouseUpイベントが発生しないことも確認しました。PreviewMouseDown後はTextBoxの動作が中断されているようです。

私がやりたいことは、TextBox.Focus()を使ってカーソルを合わせるというようなことではなく、PreviewMouseDownイベント内でShowDialog()をした後も通常のようにTextBoxを動作させてカーソルを合わせることです。
つまり、通常のようにとは次のような動作です。

1. TextBoxをクリック
2. PreviewMoseDownイベントが発生し、ダイアログが開く
3. ダイアログを操作しDialogResultを発生させメインウィンドウに返ってくる
4. PreviewMouseUpイベントが発生する
5. TextBoxにカーソルが合う

解決策が分かる方、どうかよろしくお願いいたします。

---

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <TextBox Height="30" Width="200" PreviewMouseDown="TextBox_PreviewMouseDown"/>
</Grid>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
namespace Sample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void TextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            new Dialog().ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Dialog.xaml

```
<Grid>
    <Button Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Dialog.xaml.cs

```
namespace Sample
{
    public partial class Dialog : Window
    {
        public Dialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DialogResult = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

コードを書いて確認することはしていませんが、
TextBox の PreviewMouseDown でダイアログを表示しているため
PreviewMouseUp が発生する前に、ダイアログが表示されています。

ダイアログを閉じて元のフォームに戻った時点で
マウスボタンは押されていない状態だと思うので
PreviewMouseUp が発生しないのだと思います。

解決策は、PreviewMouseDown のイベントを利用するのではなくて
PreviewMouseUp で、ダイアログの表示からその結果の処理もしてしまうことです。
＊PreviewMouseUp だけだとユーザーの操作のタイミング次第で
意図しないダイアログがでてしまうことになるので
PreviewMouseDown と組み合わせたほうがいいですね。